# How can i make a NSString display a Array Count

Tags: ios, objective-c, string-formatting

I need to display the `count` of a array in a label. To do that I need to pass the `array.count` to an `NSString`. This is what I have tried:

```
if (myArray.count > 0 ) {
   NSString *newString = @"Array count = %@", myArray.count; 
   [_myLabel setText:newString];
}
```

It didn't work. I also tried to replace the `NSString` with an `NSMutableString`, no results there. So my question is,  how do i do that?

I also tried to replace the `%@`, for `%lu`, and then add the `(unsigned long)` before the array count (just like I do to display the array count on a `NSlog`), but this did not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Array count = %d", myArray.count];
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Array count = %lu", myArray.count];
```

The reason why your code even compiled is somewhat strange: Objective C interpreted your expression as a [comma expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), ignoring the `@"Array count = %@"` portion, and assigning the value of `myArray.count` to `newString`.

This leads to undefined behavior when `setText:` tries to copy something from the "pointer" pointed to by `myArray.count`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be modern:

```
NSString *str = [@(array.count) stringValue];
```